# Create script for automatical create folder and permission folder. use tmpfiles.d in centos 7

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, centos7

i will create script automatical create folder in /var/run/postgresql

cause if i reboot postgresql 9.6 in centos 7 . folder /var/run/postgresql automatical delete and then postgrestsql cant start.

i think i will use it
`d /var/run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres` in tb 
 in tmpfiles.d/var.conf this problem or no ?

Comment: did you first check system logs? maybe you should adjust `/var/run/` permissions instead or smth?..

Comment: i check system logs .. folder /var/run/postgresql gone after reboot ..